# WebDeploy API for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, msdeploy

I've installed MSDeploy on my machine.  I am using Visual Studio 2010 and C#.  Trying to load 'Microsoft.Web.*' to code some sexy msdeploy functionality.  Perhaps I'm a level 3 tard (highly probable) but the documentation for getting this absolutely blow as@.

The error I get is:
"The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

So -- of course I try to load it via References, but it aint there.  I then Google like a mf for "webdeploy api C#" and the such and cannot for the love of the giant spaghetti monster find anything on how to install / download the msdeploy ("microsoft.web.*) .dlls, apis.

Anyone can point a brother to a link?

I did download and install "WebDeploymentSetup.msi", but nope.  I did install "webdeploy_en.msi" but nope.  Then I found this craaaazy thing called "AzurePack.exe" -- didn't even try to install that.  But, will if someone says that's it.

Thanks.

Comment: Btw, you'll find more (though not a lot) documentation on the MSDeploy command line than you will on the API, so starting there will probably be less painful.

Comment: @RichardSzalay: Yes, I've been all over the Web Deploy documentation and have a great deal of experience with the command line version.  Using the .NET libs are more desirable for this project.  I was able to answer my own question with a bit more playing around.  Thanks.

Comment: No problems. Feel free to ask more specific API questions as they come up.

Comment: You can now get it though NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Deployment/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll can be found here:
c:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll

Point a reference to that.

The only prerequisite is installing WebDeploy v3.0:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy